# Non-WebAssembly browser miner?

Tags: mining, cpu-mining, javascript

I'm trying to find a javascript-based Monero minero (or another coin I suppose would be OK), which does **not** require WebAssembly.

So far the only person I have seen figure this out is CryptoNoter, but his solution is heavily obfuscated and intertwined with his server authentication, not to mention it breaks if you don't use his pool.

Here's where he talks about his JS-only miner, and how it's speed of mining is just about as fast as it's Wasm counterpart: https://github.com/cryptonoter/CryptoNoter/issues/85

I've tried searching everywhere but am not having luck finding an open-source miner which doesn't require Wasm.